# libxml2 attribute modification C

Tags: c, libxml2

I want to change one attribute ('voltage') in my xml:

```
...
    <detector voltage="1.2e3f"/>
...
```

Here is how im trying to do it:

```
 void save_detector_attr(xmlNode *node, xmlDoc *doc){
        char *voltage;
        xmlAttrPtr s_vnewattr;
        char buf[128];
        xmlNode *cur = node->xmlChildrenNode;
        float sv;
        int cnt = 0;
        while(cur != NULL) {
            if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
                if (!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, "detector")){
                    voltage = xmlGetProp(cur, "voltage");
                    sv = atof(voltage);

                    snprintf(buf, 128, "%f", sv + 20.1 );

                    s_vnewattr = xmlNewProp (cur, "voltage", buf);
                    printf(" SAVING to voltage value: %s\n", buf);

                }
            }
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        xmlSaveFormatFile ("./mc2x.xml", doc, 1);
```

unfortunately, instead of rewriting attribute, after that function is called i'm having a new file with this:

```
<detector voltage="1.2e3f" voltage="1220.100000"/>
```

How to make that attribute will be rewriten instead of creating a new one ?

regards 
J

Comment: the first things that comes into my mind: xmlRemoveProp first, then add yours with your new value - you have to use also xmlHasProp; though I can't test it now, so I wont give it as an answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use [`xmlSetProp`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlSetProp):

```
xmlAttrPtr xmlSetProp (xmlNodePtr node, 
                       const xmlChar * name, 
                       const xmlChar * value)
```

> Set (or reset) an attribute carried by a node. If @name has a prefix, then the corresponding namespace-binding will be used, if in scope; it is an error it there's no such ns-binding for the prefix in scope.